# memory.oom_control which version is a part of the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cgroups

`memory.oom_control` is a file in **cgroup** memory subsystem.
Which upgrades increase this file in Linux?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oom_control` is implemented in [mm/memcontrol.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/memcontrol.c).
A search for a function like `mem_cgroup_oom_control_read()` leads to [this patch](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3c11ecf448eff8f12922c498b8274ce98587eb74), which is part of Linux 2.6.35.

Comment: I find this file in linux 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64.I want to know Which version appeared at the earliest.Did linux 2.2.20 have？

Comment: That is Red Hat's backport.